# Not able to get current menu ID

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm trying to get the current menu item ID. I hve found one thread that has put me on the right track: [How to get current-menu-item title as variable?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/how-to-get-current-menu-item-title-as-variable/16337#16337)

This is the code I use in my function.php file:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'current_wp_nav_menu_object' );

function current_wp_nav_menu_object( $sorted_menu_items )
{
   foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( $menu_item->current ) {
            $GLOBALS['current_menu_title'] = $menu_item->title;
            $_SESSION['current_menu_title'] = $menu_item->title;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $sorted_menu_items;
}
```

But there is one annoying problem.
The data stores is always the last clicked menu item, not the current clicked menu item.

Let'ssay I have the following menu items:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4

*(I use `echo $_SESSION['current_menu_title']` to see the result)*

Clicking the menu items in the following order, gives me the following results:

```
Item 1 -> no output
Item 2 -> outputs Item 1  
Item 4 -> outputs Item 2  
Item 1 -> outputs Item 4
```

Why isn't the current clicked menu item outputted?

Comment: Take a look at the attached filter function over [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4388/how-to-add-css-classes-to-only-one-wp-nav-menu).

Comment: @kaiser, can you show me an example of how I can use the walker to get current menu ID?

Comment: There's no walker. Only a function attached to a filter. Just `var_dump( $var );` the variables at the top of the function (`$items, $menu, $args`) and take a look in what they provide.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen a menu object does not have the 'current' property, does it? Not that I ever seen it, at least. So you can get close to what you're asking by comparing the current post/page ID (`get_the_ID()`) with the items' `object_id` property, when they match - boom! you got your currently selected menu.

```
function wpse25992_store_current_id( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        // this is the currently displayed object
        if ( $item->object_id == get_the_ID() )
            $_SESSION['current_menu_title'] = $item->title;
    }

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpse31748_exclude_menu_items', null, 3 );
```